Question related to Database Design in SQL Server
I have two tables: Products and ProductVersions. The table structures are as follows:
Products Table:
ProductId
RegionId
ActiveProductVersionId
isDisabled
ApplicationId

ProductVersions Table:
ProductVersionId
ProductId
Name
ReleaseDate
DateCreated
DateModified
Status
Creator

Requirements:

If an ApplicationID is passed in, I need to get all the products for
a given application and fetch their active versions.
The products must not be disabled.
The result set should support various sorting and filtering options based on the following columns: DateModified, Name, ReleaseDate, Status

Current Issue:
When I join the Products table to the ProductVersions table on ActiveProductVersionId, the clustered index on ProductVersions is being used. However, any other columns for filtering or ordering end up in the predicate section, resulting in a not so optimal performance. My idea was to create one stored procedure for each filtering option and then have an index for that option but since in any given case I have to join Products with ProductVersions table, the clustered index will be used and the index I plan on creating wont' be used.
Potential Solution Considered:
One solution I considered is moving the columns ApplicationId, isDisabled, ActiveProductVersionId to the ProductVersions table directly. This would allow more direct indexing and might solve the query performance issue. For example, for dateModified I can create an index (applicationId, isDisabled, isActiveFormVersion, DateModified) However, this approach leads to data duplication as this information is now captured for every version of the product instead of the product itself.
    -- Create Products table
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    RegionId INT NOT NULL,
    ActiveProductVersionId INT,
    IsDisabled BIT NOT NULL,
    ApplicationId INT
);

-- Create ProductVersions table
CREATE TABLE ProductVersions (
    ProductVersionId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductId INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ReleaseDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DateModified DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Creator VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the index on Products table
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Products_AppId_IsDisabled_ActiveProdVerId
ON Products (ApplicationId, IsDisabled, ActiveProductVersionId);

-- Insert sample data into Products table
INSERT INTO Products (ProductId, RegionId, ActiveProductVersionId, IsDisabled, ApplicationId)
VALUES
    (1, 101, 1001, 0, 10001),
    (2, 102, 1002, 0, 10001),
    (3, 103, 1003, 1, 10002),
    (4, 104, 1004, 0, 10002),
    (5, 105, 1005, 0, 10003),
    (6, 106, 1006, 1, 10003),
    (7, 107, 1007, 0, 10004),
    (8, 108, 1008, 0, 10001);

-- Insert sample data into ProductVersions table
INSERT INTO ProductVersions (ProductVersionId, ProductId, Name, ReleaseDate, DateCreated, DateModified, Status, Creator)
VALUES
    (1001, 1, 'Product A v1', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', 'Released', 'Creator A'),
    (1002, 2, 'Product B v1', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-02', 'Released', 'Creator B'),
    (1003, 3, 'Product C v1', '2023-03-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-03-02', 'Released', 'Creator C'),
    (1004, 4, 'Product D v1', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', 'Released', 'Creator D'),
    (1005, 5, 'Product E v1', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', 'Released', 'Creator E'),
    (1006, 6, 'Product F v1', '2023-06-01', '2023-06-01', '2023-06-02', 'Released', 'Creator F'),
    (1007, 7, 'Product G v1', '2023-07-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-07-02', 'Released', 'Creator G'),
    (1008, 8, 'Product H v1', '2023-08-01', '2023-08-01', '2023-08-02', 'Released', 'Creator H');

DECLARE @ApplicationId INT = 10001;

SELECT pv.ProductId, 
FROM Products p
JOIN ProductVersions pv ON p.ActiveProductVersionId = pv.ProductVersionId
WHERE p.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId
  AND p.IsDisabled = 0
ORDER BY pv.DateModified DESC;

Question:
Is moving the columns to the ProductVersions table a good approach despite the data duplication or is there a better way to handle this scenario to optimize filtering and ordering across both tables?
Any advice on how to structure the tables or optimize the query would be greatly appreciated!

Have you considered combining the two tables into an indexed view? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16?


resulting in a not so optimal performance

How so?
If I'm inferring the situation correctly, you'd probably want to have on Product:
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ApplicationId, IsDisabled, ProductId)
This is assuming you're lumping the products of multiple "applications" together in one table, and are therefore usually going to want to filter on ApplicationId. And you've said you invariably want to exclude disabled products.
On ProductVersion, you would want:
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProductId, ProductVersionId)
You would then join like:
FROM Products AS p
JOIN ProductVersions AS pv
ON pv.Product = p.Product
AND pv.ProductVersionId = p.ActiveProductVersionId

Unless your product list is extreme in size, I don't see why the performance of this kind of simple query would be unsatisfactory - and I would only cross that bridge if I came to it.
As an aside, it's common for multiple applications to share a database, but it isn't a good practice to force the distinct master data of multiple applications into the same tables just because that data happens to share the same storage shape and the same name (but not the same meaning or scope of usage).
So if you have two different applications which maintain two different master lists of products, you'd normally use two separate tables (each one owned by its respective application), rather than just adding an ApplicationId to a shared table.
